# What is the equivalent of Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider for Az PowerShell

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, azure

I have script that looks for Virtual Machines in Azure that are older than 60 days. Is it possible to do this with Get-AzLog to retrieve VM creation time?

I noticed that Get-AzureRmLog is becoming deprecated in 2024 and I am looking for the equivalent command for $logs below in Az PowerShell

$logs = Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Compute -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

```
    foreach ($log in $logs) {
        if (($log.OperationName.Value -eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write') -and ($log.SubStatus.Value -eq 'Created')) {
            $vmInfo = "- Found VM creation at $($log.EventTimestamp) for VM $($log.Id.split("/")[8]) in Resource Group $($log.ResourceGroupName) found in Azure logs"
            $vmId = "   - ID $($log.Id)"
            $vmCreationTime = $($log.EventTimestamp)
            $Status = 'noncompliant'
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's truly a 1:1 functionality you should be able to use the [automatic migrate tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/quickstart-migrate-azurerm-to-az-automatically?view=azps-8.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to
[Get-AzureRmLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermlog?view=azurermps-6.13.0)
is the new
[Get-AzLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azlog?view=azps-0.10.0).

You could also look at the Microsoft article
[Quickstart: Automatically migrate PowerShell scripts from AzureRM to the Az PowerShell module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/quickstart-migrate-azurerm-to-az-automatically?view=azps-8.2.0).

The article describes an automatic method for migrating all your scripts.
But take backups before using this method.